# npm err notarget no matching version found for bootstrap@3

Tags: node.js, npm, twitter-bootstrap-3, installation

I'm new to npm, I am trying to install bootstrap 3 into my angular 6 generated project but when I run the following command:

```
npm install --save boostrap@3
```

I'm getting an error:

> npm ERR! code ETARGET
>   npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for boostrap@3
>   npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
>   npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

Comment: package name is `bootstrap3` - so it's `npm install bootstrap3` [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap3). You can select a specific version by using `@` or leave it as it is an install latest

Answer (score 8):

There is no package boostrap, there is a package called bootstrap. It appears you left out the first "t".

Comment: Thank you very much my dyslexia is acting up ... now I feel really stupid for not spell checking. Thank you again.

Comment: This is the thing I was doing for about 10 minutes